# Generating correlated random numbers from Normal Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation

If I have a sequence taken from X~N (μ1 , σ1 ). Is it possible to generate a sequence of numbers drawn from Y~N (μ2 , σ2) such that X and Y have correlation ρ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Let $X_1\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $X_2\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ be independent.

Define $Y=aX_1 + bX_2 +c$.
Then find $a, b, c$ so that $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$ and 
$$
{E(X_1-\mu_1)(Y-\mu_2)\over \sigma_1\sigma_2}=\rho.
$$